# ping shows different outputs

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, router, cisco-commands

Both VLANS are working, and pings from R1 to R0 and vice versa also work successfully. But when I ping from the pink PCs to the blue PCs I get destination unreachable, and when I send pings from the blue PCs to the pink PCs I get request time out. where does the error lay?

[image]

SW0 configuration:

```
    SW0#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1129 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname SW0
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 191.120.128.2 255.255.255.128
!
ip default-gateway 191.120.128.1
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

RO configuration:

```
R0#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 587 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R0
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 191.120.128.1 255.255.255.128
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 191.120.128.193 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip classless
ip route 191.120.128.0 255.255.255.128 191.120.128.194 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
no cdp run
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

R1 configuration:

```
R1#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 634 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 191.120.128.194 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 191.120.128.129 255.255.255.192
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip classless
ip route 191.120.128.0 255.255.255.128 191.120.128.193 
ip route 191.120.128.128 255.255.255.192 191.120.128.193 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

SW1 configurations:

```
SW1#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1133 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname SW1
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 191.120.128.130 255.255.255.192
!
ip default-gateway 191.120.128.129
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R0 is missing a route to Subnet C, 191.120.120.128/26.

Pinging from pink to blue, R0 returns the ICMP error to the *echo request* sender, prompting the message. Pinging in the other direction, R0 returns the ICMP error to the *echo reply* sender, which has no user process to notify.

Note that the addresses you're using are not private, so you'd have problems connecting that network to the Internet. Check out RFC 1918 for the address ranges for private use (192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, 10.0.0.0/8).

Comment: THANK YOU, it worked!!!, I just added an ip route from R0 to subnet C